# jQuery: How to get intellisense working on cached element

Tags: jquery, intellisense, element

How could I get jQuery Intellisense working on cached Elements. If I do the following, I get no Intellisense:

```
var elem = $j('#elemID');
elem.height(100);
```

If I change the code above to the followung, than I have intellisense, but is that the right way? Am I not recreating a jQuery objectfrom a jQuery object?

```
var $(elem) = $j('#elemID');
$(elem).height(100);
```

Comment: Yes you are. The first code block you posted is the proper way. Don't modify your code to make the IDE happy, it's the IDE's job to understand your code...

Comment: Well I don't want intellisense for the IDE... but for me. It's reasonable that working with intellisense support makes it easier to avoid errors while typing. And it's way more comfortable to simply type 'haso' hit enter instead of typing the hole string 'hasOwnProperty'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that I got Intellisense now, the trick is to start the variable names for jQuery-Object with $.

```
var $elem = $j('#elemID');
var height = $elem.height(100); // I got intellisense here!
```

Doing this gives me intellisense and a better distinction between cached jQuery-objects and normal objects/variables: $elem is a jQuery-object and height just a normal variable / number.